# Find the probability density function of $Y=|Ax+n|^2$

Tags: probability-distributions

I know that the pdf of $Ax+n$ is a Gaussian one and I want to calculate the pdf of $Y=|Ax+n|^2$.
Is this possible?

Comment: The square of a non-zero-mean gaussian is a noncentral chi-squared distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution)

Comment: Yes.$\mbox{}\mbox{}$